# Copy everything in a worksheet vba

Tags: vba, excel

```
' Copy
wb.Sheets(wsSource.Name).Range("A1:W79").Copy
' Paste Special
wbTarget.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:W79").PasteSpecial xlValues
wbTarget.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:W79").PasteSpecial xlFormats
```

This code allows me to copy everything in a range of A1:W79. How can I modify this Range so that it selects everything that contains value in a worksheet. For example, worksheet might contain values from C7:G20 etc.

Comment: Work with `UsedRange` Property

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35712424/how-to-find-the-true-last-cell-in-any-worksheet

Answer (score 4):

I'd go like follows:

```
With wb.Sheets(wsSource.Name).UsedRange
    .Copy
    With wbTarget.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(.Address)
        .PasteSpecial xlValues
        .PasteSpecial xlFormats
    End With
End With
```

Comment: @Desmond, did you get through it?