# .Select, .Activesheet, .Activecell etc...

Tags: vba, excel

For this question, I refer to the post below to clarify myself:
[Why is my conditional format offset when added by VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12421029/why-is-my-conditional-format-offset-when-added-by-vba/12424894#12424894)

In many, many posts I see these days, OP's are silently allowed to use .Activate, .Select, .Offset, etc... while they are an open door to potential bugs (most often caused by the end users).
The code is sometimes even supported.

**My question: Is there one valid situation where you would use any of these statements without direct alternatives being available that catch typical bugs resulting from these stmts?**

I'm referring to *dynamic* solutions that in my opinion are a *must* when developing for Excel. 
Personally, in more than 6 years I can't remember a single case where I needed it; it seems always to be one of the the worst options available. In my previous company, it was a silent rule never to use it and it only made my VBA life (and that of the end user) better.

Why I create this question is because I think that it is worthful to make newcomers into VBA aware of the risks they take when using these statements (by experience proven risks when the End Users do something unexpected - in the end they don't have any affection with VBA) and to propose direct alternatives (I won't state I always did that before myself, but I feel in my gut that there is something wrong with just offering quick solutions on already bug monsters).

I believe that when silently allowed (which it automatically enhances in this case), starting VBA developers will create a growing amount of tools the wrong way (and thus also newcomers will inherit the behaviour - which they will also learn from Stack Overflow since Google returns the results they look for (!)).
If the developer is not aware why he "can" use a "select" and in which situations it is a potential bug, (s)he should never use it imho. Personally I might use the select stmt in the immediate window to do some quick checks on dynamic range definition (bug mode), but not in written code.

The result makes VBA in the end even more unpopular than it is already; the language will be made the victim in case trouble appear (yet it is imho still the "best" programming support available for the Excel and Access applications). I've seen this happen too many times in a large company where VBA is always "shit".

This is only my own honest experience.
It is not a question of being right or wrong; I am interested in hearing your point of view on the question.

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros

Answer (score 3):

I agree about Select and Activate, but not ActiveWorkbook, ActiveSheet, and ActiveCell (I agree that they are abused, but not that they should be avoided, per se).  There are definitely legitimate uses for those.  I have a program that automates a "fill series" that does so from the ActiveCell.  My program can't predict what cells will be used; it's up the user to select it.  That's part of the user interface.

However, there are three situations where I have had to use Select (now four that I read about zoom, but I don't ever use it).

1. Conditional Formatting.  There is a work around using Application.ConvertFormula, but it's worse than just storing the selection, selecting the right cell, doing the deed, and reselecting the previous selection.
2. Data Validation.  Same reason.
3. Shapes. I wish I could remember the details, but it's been too long since I've worked with Shapes.  There was something I couldn't do without selecting the shape first.

Ridding code of Select and Activate is a noble fight.

Comment: I totally agree, IF the purpose is that a user explicitly needs to select a cell on which actions will be performed. In all other cases (which is the case in a good 99% percent of the time of what I see), I would lookup the ranges to format / validate on a dynamic level that doesn't require to be 'Active'. Why would it? For the select, I also don't see why conditional formatting and Data validation need a select... You need a clear object identification, but why adding being selected as extra requirement? For ranges/cell cond formatting, I use If Then/Select Case; after all it's programming.

Comment: Well, the reason why I post it is because it bothers me terribly when I read things like: Sheets(1).Activate -> ActiveSheet.range(x,y).select etc... I see it all the time lately, I just find it hard to reply to that, even though I will if it helps. In the link I mention in my current post, the reply accepted is: ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Activate This is just asking for troubles... However, the next person who reads this will do exactly the same. And in the end, VBA will be "considered" a language that has many bugs. Which it hasn't.

Comment: re #3, there are some instances I've found when applying formatting to series data in charts, where `Select` is occasionally necessary. This seems IMO to be a bug with Excel and not a design feature.  Word is a different animal, which relies a lot more on Selection object, and PowerPoint, too, there are some sort of operations that can only be performed when the application and slide/shape are visible (while this doesn't strictly mean "activate", it's similar in some sense)

Comment: @DavidZemens Yeah, maybe it was charts that I was thinking of. Whenever I answer a Word VBA question, I make a point of not using `Selection`. It's often difficult and sometimes impossible, as you say.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few methods in Excel that require Activate or ActiveSheet/ActiveWorkbook etc as I've been caught with a gotchas on occasion. The only one I can remember at the moment is the zoom property. Zoom affects only the sheet that's currently active in the window so to zoom all sheets you would need something like

```
Sub SetZoom()
Dim ws As Worksheet
    Application.screenupdating = false

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        ws.Select
        ActiveWindow.Zoom = 80
    Next ws

    Application.screenupdating = true
End Sub
```

Comment: Ok, that would seem valid. In this case you would use ActiveWindow consciously because it wouldn't have a purpose to perform a zoom on an inactive sheet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.Select` to determine what a user's view is after running code - for example if you create a new workbook in your code, without using `Activate` or `Select` your user may not know this happens.

I frequently end a long operation creating a new workbook or other largescale data manipulations with

```
FinalViewWorkbook.FinalViewSheet.Range("A1").Select
```

Just to inform the end user about something - "oh, this created a new workbook of reports!" etc.

Comment: That seems valid use to me too. Not for data manipulation, but as an indication. Perhaps a set of rules regarding the use of these statements should be set up.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is important in this matter to distinguish some:

- `Active`-something: Only use this if it is absolutely necessary to know what the user is handling right now. In my experience, this is usually Data Validation or Active Sheet Detection (e.g. "Update the Sheet where the user just pressed a button").
- `Selection`: Somewhat the same as `Active`, only use readingly. Userful either for Data Validation, or for gimmicks like "Interpret the cell value as path and open it in a new Explorer Window".
- `Select`, `Activate`: Imho different from `Selection`, as it actually changes the selected Cell, Sheet etc. *Never ever* use this to read or write data, since it enables a user to mess up your program by just clicking. Users love to click. Only use this to Zoom (see answer by @user3357963) or clean up a view after your code has finished working (see answer by @enderland). (I'm not sure, but I think handling the PageView also requires ActiveSheet).
- `Select`, `Activate` the 2nd: If you are new to VBA and are learning via Macro Recorder, you will find a lot of code generated like this: 
  First `Range("A5").Select`, then `Selection.Value="NewValue"`. Join this to `Range("A5").Value="NewValue"`.
- `Offset`: Personally, I don't have a problem using `.Offset()` - I never encountered problems with this command. Instead, I think it's a handy way of saying "The cell next to this" without having to go through "This cell's sheet at this cell's row and column+1" every time.

> In many, many posts I see these days, OP's are silently allowed to use .Activate, .Select, .Offset, etc...

I agree with this. Even though it's easier to just give the necessary answer to make a piece of code work, the use of `ActiveCell.Value` and the like should be discouraged. This will be much easier if there's a well explained Thread to link to, as this here is hopefully becoming :-)

Answer (score 0):

From my perspective, with few exceptions, the only time you should use `Select` is as a user input, and only then after careful consideration of alternative design/UI requirements.

For example, I'd say it's generally not advisable to rely on `Selection` to let user define a Range object when this method keeps execution within the code:

```
Dim myRange as Range
Set myRange = Application.InputBox("Select your range", Type:=8)
```

However, if you need to prompt users to select a particular shape or object on the worksheet, then *maybe* it's better to let them make a `Selection` (however, this can open up a Pandora's Box of problems without good error-handling and logic to prevent undesired user actions...).

Here is an example of one such exception that I have in PowerPoint. I have some RibbonUI XML and VBA that adds buttons to the `Shapes` right-click context menu in PowerPoint, and adds similar buttons to the Ribbon itself. These are seamless UI that give the end-user a more "native" experience with the application -- users want to be able to right-click the chart and then run some macro procedures against that selected chart or table, etc. They don't want to press a button to open up a user form and scroll through a listbox of generic shape names or GUIDs.

The procedure code needs to examine the `Selection` in order to handle it properly so I can use something like below, where

```
Sub UpdateOrEditSelection(update As Boolean)
'This procedure invoked when user edits/updates a chart.
Dim uid As Variant
Dim sel As Selection
Dim s As Integer
Dim chartsToUpdate As Object
Dim multipleShapes As Boolean
Dim sld As Slide
Set sel = ppPres.Windows(1).Selection

If update Then
    Set chartsToUpdate = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Select Case sel.Type
        Case ppSelectionShapes
            For s = 1 To sel.ShapeRange.count
                uid = sel.ShapeRange(s).Name
                '....
                '...
                '..
                '.
            Next
        Case ppSelectionSlides
            For Each sld In sel.SlideRange
                For s = 1 To sld.Shapes.count
                    uid = sld.Shapes(s).Name
                    '....
                    '...
                    '..
                    '.

                Next
            Next
        Case ppSelectionText
            s = 1
            If sel.ShapeRange(s).HasTable Or sel.ShapeRange(s).HasChart Then
                uid = sel.ShapeRange(s).Name
                '....
                '...
                '..
                '.

            End If
    End Select
 '....
 '...
 '..
 '.
```

**Where does it come from?**

The Macro Recorder. Essentially, this feature records every literal user input: scrolling, selecting, viewing, activating, default properties, etc., to the point of overkill. While this is sometimes helpful, it does encourage bad code written by people who don't know that it's bad, but I will not belabor that point which has been made here:

[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)

**What is better, conceptually?**

Program to the objects directly. If you're merely using VBA to mimic keystrokes and mouseclicks, you're doing it wrong.

**Exceptions:**

I've found when applying formatting to series data in charts, where `Select` is occasionally necessary. This seems IMO to be a bug with Excel and not a design feature.

Other applications (because VBA is not *only* Excel):

- Word is a different animal, which relies a lot more on Selection object
- In PowerPoint there are some sort of operations that can only be performed when the application and slide/shape are visible or otherwise in view. While you don't usually need to "select" anything, it does require more cumbersome code.

I found this snippet in my App:

```
    Set tb = cht.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, ptLeft, tBoxTop, ptWidth, ptHeight)
    tb.Select  '<--- KEEP THIS LINE OTHERWISE TEXTBOX ALIGNMENT WILL NOT WORK ## ## ##
```

And this:

```
    'PPT requires selecting the slide in order to export an image preview/jpg
sld.Select
ppPres.Windows(1).View.GotoSlide sld.SlideIndex
sld.Shapes(1).Chart.Export imgPath, ppShapeFormatJPG
```

And this, dealing with individual `Point` objects:

```
        pt.Select
        pt.format.Line.Visible = msoTrue
        pt.format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
        pt.MarkerSize = pt.MarkerSize + 2
```

This is not an exhaustive list, just some examples of exceptions that I found.  While these were from PowerPoint, the charts in PowerPoint use the same object model as Excel so I would not be surprised if some of these also need to be hacked in Excel, and Word, too.

- Outlook: I don't do much with Outlook, it is a lot like Word and actually uses the Word object model in the Inspector, but what little I do with Outlook does rely on things like ActiveInspector, etc.

Neither Word or PowerPoint have a "macro recorder" anymore (actually, I think Word might but it's so damn impotent as to be useless) and by the time most people do any development in other applications, they've figured most of this out already.