# Sheet_variable.UsedRange.Column does not give the expected/desired result. Why?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I'm interested in using a variable of type workbook in Excel VBA where I would hold an Excel file like this:

```
Set mWB = Application.Workbooks("C:\Central.xlsx")
```

and then I would like to hold a worksheet from this file similarly in a Sheet variable.

```
Set aWS = mWB.Sheets("Sheet1")
```

**In Sheet1 inside Central.xlsx, I have values in Range(A1:D6)**

However, when I do this: `MsgBox aWS.UsedRange.Column` , I get 1. **I was expecting 6 (6 populated rows)**
and when I do this: `MsgBox aWS.UsedRange.Row` I get 1 again. **I was expecting 4 (4 populated rows).**

Where is the mistake please?

Comment: You probably meant `MsgBox aWS.UsedRange.Columns.Count` (Column with an `s` at the end) - same for rows.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much assylias. Also I wasn't sure what UsedRange.Row does. Or UsedRange.Column. They show from doing a few tests now the **first** populated row/column number from the sheet.

Comment: Yes that's what it does: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196952.aspx

Comment: @assylias, your comment should be posted as a solution. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably meant to use `MsgBox aWS.UsedRange.Columns.Count` instead (Column with an s at the end) - same for rows.

`Range.Row` [returns the first row of the range](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196952.aspx).

Comment: +1, @Sam, also see my post here: [used range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7423022/excel-getting-the-actual-usedrange/7423252#7423252)