# VBA Remove format from empty cells in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, format

I need a quick code to clean the format of all the cells that are empty.
I have written this code, but it is too slow. Is there a way to make it quicker?

```
Sub removeFormatEmpty()
    'Declaration of variables
    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    Dim rcell As Range

    For Each sheet In Worksheets
        sheet.Activate
        'Cells.UnMerge
        For Each rcell In sheet.UsedRange.Cells
            If rcell.MergeCells = True Then
                rcell.UnMerge
            End If
            If rcell.Value = "" Then
                rcell.ClearFormats
            End If
        Next rcell
    Next sheet
End Sub
```

This code works, however it is slow as it needs to go cell by cell. Is there a way to select the whole range except the cells with content?

Update:
Thank you to the comments of bobajob and jordan I've been able to update the code and make it much more faster and optimized. It is the new code:

```
Sub removeFormatEmptyImproved()
    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each sheet In Worksheets
        'sheet.Activate
        sheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).ClearFormats
    Next sheet

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

So now it is solved.

Comment: Try `sheet.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)`

Comment: You don't need to `Activate` the sheet to make changes in it, also use `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` and `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` at the start of the sub to speed things up, but remember to set them back to `True` and `xlCalculationAutomatic`, respectively, at the end of your sub

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Firstly, you don't have to check whether a cell *is* merged before unmerging it. So to unmerge all cells in `sheet`...

  ```
  sheet.UsedRange.UnMerge
  ```
- You don't need to activate a sheet before altering it
- As mentioned in the comments, you can alter all cells at once by using

  ```
  sheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).ClearFormats
  ```
- Turning `Calculation` to manual and `ScreenUpdating` to false is an easy go-to method to speed most VBA code up!

  ```
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  ' <other code>
  ' Include error handling so that these are always set back!        

  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  ```

So your resulting `Sub` would be

```
Sub removeFormatEmpty()

    Dim sheet As Worksheet

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each sheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets   

        sheet.UsedRange.UnMerge

        sheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).ClearFormats

    Next sheet

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

A final step to speed things up would be to dig into your `UsedRange` a little more. It can be notorious for remembering long-unused cells and being far bigger than necessary. If you know your sheet layout, there may be a way to restrict the range you are working with.

See some methods for doing this here:
[Getting the actual usedrange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7423022/getting-the-actual-usedrange)