# VBA Remove format from empty cells in Excel (while ignoring the merged cells)

Tags: excel, vba, formatting

I came across this link in the forum
[VBA Remove format from empty cells in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41286930/vba-remove-format-from-empty-cells-in-excel)

However, I would like to clear the formatting of empty cells, ignoring the merged cells.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. You will need to make two updates here:

1. Update the sheet name in code to the sheet of interest
2. Update the range in code to the relevant range you want this code to work on (*for testing purposes, the range is currently set to `ws.Range("A1:A30")`*)

The macro will loop trough each cell in the provided range (*which you need to update per #2*) and will check to see if the cell is both **empty AND unmerged**. If the cell meets this criteria, we will add it to a range variable (`Format_Range`) and continue the loop. Once the loop is complete, clear the formatting of the variable range all at once.

---

```
Sub Custom_Format()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")        'Update Sheet Name

Dim Target As Range, Format_Range As Range

For Each Target In ws.Range("A1:A30")                              'Update Range to run macro on
    If Target.MergeCells = False And Target = "" Then
        If Not Format_Range Is Nothing Then
            Set Format_Range = Union(Target, Format_Range)
        Else
            Set Format_Range = Target
        End If
    End If
Next Target

'Make sure the range is not empty before removing format
If Not Format_Range is Nothing Then Format_Range.ClearFormats

End Sub
```

---

### Sample Output

Here is a before (*`Column A`*) and after (*`Column B`*) photo when using the macro. Note that all unmerged cells had the formatting stripped from them when they were blank while merged cells kept their formatting regardless.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you could use `SpecialCells` property of `Range` object and get all blank cells on which testing if they are part of a merged area:

```
Dim cel As Range
With ActiveSheet ' <- change this to your actual sheet reference of interest
    With .UsedRange ' <- change this to your actual range reference of interest
        For Each cel In .SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeBlanks).Cells
            If Not cel.MergeCells Then Debug.Print cel.ClearFormats
        Next
    End With
End With
```