# Adjust code to not error when filtering based on UsedRange.Rows

Tags: vba, excel

I have a snippet of code that filters a worksheet (snowCsatDetails) based on two different ranges.  Once filtered, the sheet could have 0 rows after the header, or 1 to many rows.  Once filtered, the second piece of code counts to the last filled row, and then copies those rows (if they exist) to a new worksheet (snowCsatSummary).

```
    snowCsatDetails.Range("A1:F" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=5, _
        Criteria1:="=1", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=2"
    snowCsatDetails.Range("A1:F" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=2, _
        Criteria1:=Array(var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6, var7), Operator:=xlFilterValues

    filteredLastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    filledRows = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A" & filteredLastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count
    snowCsatSummary.Activate

    snowCsatDetails.Range("A2:A" & filteredLastRow).Copy
    Range("A13").PasteSpecial
    snowCsatDetails.Range("B2:B" & filteredLastRow).Copy
    Range("B13").PasteSpecial
    snowCsatDetails.Range("C2:C" & filteredLastRow).Copy
    Range("D13").PasteSpecial
    snowCsatDetails.Range("E2:E" & filteredLastRow).Copy
    Range("F13").PasteSpecial
    snowCsatDetails.Range("F2:F" & filteredLastRow).Copy
    Range("G13").PasteSpecial
```

The code has worked fine so far since data has always existed after filtering the first worksheet.  However, today, when filtered, no rows happen to exist.  The code now errors out on the "filledRows" line.  It appears that this is because there is nothing to copy.

So, I tried adding error handling to this line (`On Error Resume Next` above it and `On Error GoTo 0` below it) but this causes the code to ignore the filtered rows altogether, and copy every row of data to the new worksheet.

I am not sure if it is something simple that I am missing, or more complex.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`UsedRange` is noted as unreliable and using `Find` is preferable. See [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7423022/getting-the-actual-usedrange) for example.

If you have a simple set-up though, and are aware of potential issues with `UsedRange`, and wish to continue with your current code, then you could check whether the `UsedRange.Rows.Count` is greater than 1. It will be 1 as a minimum, even if the worksheet has no content.

```
filteredLastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

If filteredLastRow > 1 Then
    ' there is some data to process..
End If
```

The fact that this number won't be 0 should not be a concern because it appears that you have a persistent header row anyway.

Comment: Oh okay.  I had thought that zero rows (after the header) meant that it would be 0 minimum, and not 1.  I will have to look into `Find` since I have no idea why this is breaking if it is not actually ever 0.

Comment: A range of `A2:A1` would be upside-down.