# Create Range excluding column in middle

Tags: vba, excel

I have the problem of needing to exclude a column in the middle of my excel worksheet. Is there a way of creating a range that excludes a column not on the edges of the data. The range is dynamic ranging from A1:AA#. The column "F" needs to be excluded from this range. This range needs to be stored for use in a pivotTable.

```
Range("A1:E4,G1:J4").Select
```

This is how the excel macro recorder creates a range with a gap, but I cannot find a way to modify this so the last cell is dynamic.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as you should avoid using the `.Select` Method, you should also avoid using the `.UsedRange` when possible ([See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7423022/getting-the-actual-usedrange)).

You can try something like this. It is not as clean, but may prove to be less bug prone.

```
Dim LRow As Long
LRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim MyRange1 As Range, MyRange2 As Range, BigRange As Range

Set MyRange1 = Range("A1:E" & LRow)
Set MyRange2 = Range("G1:J" & LRow)
Set BigRange = Application.Union(MyRange1, MyRange2)

BigRange.Select
```

You can then refer to your `BigRange` directly moving forward.

Answer (score 1):

If you have only one set of data in your sheet, you could try something like that :

`Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("A:E,G:AA")).Select`

This will select everything that contains data up to column AA on the sheet except for column F.

Whenever possible , you should avoid using `.select` `.activate` but you only provide one line of your code so I can't help you much on that part except redirect you to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what im looking for. Im not using select instead Var = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("A:E,G:AA")) which creates the range for use.

Answer (score 0):

you could use

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Intersect(Range("A:E,G:AA"), Rows(1).Resize(Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row))
```

where the column index in  `Cells(Rows.Count, 1)` lets you choose what column size your range after