# Excel VSTO - Edit filtered cell - Strange behavior

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

While programming in VSTO, I've hit a strange issue and wanted to ask if someone already experimented it before?

Using the following method, I get a range from a worksheet: `myRange = worksheet.usedRange`. 
I edit it using a simple assignment to an array of the property `range.value2 = newValues`.

It perfectly works in most of the cases. 
But, if some of the rows inside my range are hidden (for instance, due to a filtering), those never get edited. Even worse, they are often filled in with very strange values, probably coming from an usage of an unassigned variable.

I've tried to solve this issue and quickly got to posts like this one (here in VBA): http://www.clear-lines.com/blog/post/Weird-Excel-behavior-with-Filter-and-Hidden-column.aspx
Those seem to reference similar issues. But, never got resolved.

Do you know if this is a known behavior of excel VSTO? And if yes, did anyone find solutions to overcome this?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you unfilter / unhide before assigning new values? Also, in VBA, `UsedRange` is considered bad practice as it is unreliable.

Comment: Yes, I can unfilter. But, the problem is that I cannot re-apply filter after I save it, because of another bug: 
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/281fdbc5-6535-497f-b427-f69f4b092e24/excel-vsto-accessing-autofilters-array-criteria-throws-exceptions?forum=exceldev

Which basically means that you cannot access "criteria2" of filters. So, there is no way to save & reapply them. 

Thanks for the notice about `usedRange`. But, can you provide more explanation about it or a link that indicates why is this not suggested & how to overcome this? 

Thanks

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7423252/6706419) goes into a little detail about `UsedRange`

Comment: I can repro the issue too, so I think we can submit an feature request in the https://officespdev.uservoice.com first(although the best choice is submit an bug).